# iAd not showing test ads on device

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, iad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iAds not working in Simulator and device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254920/iads-not-working-in-simulator-and-device)

I just published an app with iAds, and they work fine. But on running an updated build I have problems. The iAd test ads show up on the simulator as expected, but I get nothing on the device. Output says that the error delegate method is called, with a message about no ad inventory when I NSLog the error. Why aren't they showing?

**EDIT:** So after 24 hours of no iAds, they are now fully functional on both the simulator and device. All I can think of is that it was a server-side issue, as I didn't change a single line of code. It also may have had something to do with the time zone change that occurred early this morning, as some people have stated that [resetting the clock helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720459/iad-error-ad-inventory-unavailable).

Comment: I've reinstalled the app several times and it never works on the device--only the simulator.